# Remove part of column name post the second "_"

Tags: r, gsub, substr

I have a vector which has names of the columns

`group <- c("amount_bin_group", "fico_bin_group", "cltv_bin_group", "p_region_bin")`

I want to replace the part after the second "_" from each element i.e. I want it to be

`group <- c("amount_bin", "fico_bin", "cltv_bin", "p_region")`

I can split this into two vectors and try gsub or substr. However, it would be nice to do that in vector. Any thoughts?

I checked other posts regarding the same question, but none of them has this framework

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [How to delete everything after nth delimiter in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062016/how-to-delete-everything-after-nth-delimiter-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> sub("(.*)_.*$", "\\1", group)
[1] "amount_bin" "fico_bin"   "cltv_bin"   "p_region"
```